# How to change the size of window DepthBasics

Tags: c++, kinect-sdk

I am a beginner in programming and still learning to use kinect 2 SDK to create an application where I click on a point to retrieve its depth value.

The dialog box which shows the depth output in DepthBasics D2D seems to be larger than 512x424 and upon clicking in that window, gives different pixel coordinates than the actual point in the depth image. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Place the bitmap in a panel/grid of its own that is the size required for the kinect data (ie 512x424) and reference the points relative to the panel/grid instead of the window.